# Bluetooth joystick becomes unresponsive

Tags: 18.04, bluetooth, devices, input-devices, joystick

I'm using a decent Bluetooth joystick to control an electric vehicle. I was using a Windows PC and a microcontroller recently and I had no problem with this joystick. I've decided to go with ROS (Robot Operating System which is a middleware) to control my vehicle. I've configured ROS, Ubuntu Mate 18.04 on Raspberry Pi 3B.

Everything works as the same as it did on Windows PC setup. However, this joystick sometimes goes unresponsive like 10 seconds. The vehicle still processes the last message it received so it goes forward/backward and crashes to an obstacle.

During that unresponsive time, there is no output when I do

```
cat /dev/input/js0
```

And however, when I examine the working of this joystick using js-gtk, I don't see a problem at all. What could be done to fix this issue?

Comment: @tatsu A python script in a package on ROS simply gets the status of buttons and  axes of the joystick (from /dev/input/js0), publishes this message to microcontroller. Therefore I don't think there is a problem related to it.

Comment: While script is running, cat /dev/input/js0 also shows no sign of activity when joystick goes unresponsive.